# How to display array of object in typescript including null as well

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array  which can contain null and array of objects I have to display it in a react table . if null cell will not show anything if not, then cell will show array of value from the object .  Need to know how can I read such array ?
My table column will look like Genre(s) column in blow image.
Thanks!

```
array = [null, null, 
 [
  {id:"1", value:"abc"},
  {id:"2", value:"def"}
 ],
 [
  {id:"1", value:"efg"}, 
  {id:"2", value:"jkl"}
 ], 
  null, 
 [
  {id:"1", value:"an"},
  {id:"2", value:"jef"}
 ]
]

result should be 
 myarray = [null,null,[abc,def],[efg,jkl],null,[an,jef]]
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code you tried so far

Comment: what do you mean by table cell? is it an HTML table? if not, do you simply want to remove the null values?

Comment: react table but I don't want to remove null values. In case of null cell will be empty else it will show the value.

Comment: data.items.map(item => item. array).forEach(item => item.name===undefined?null: item.name)  giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an `Array.map` to produce the result.

```js
const myarray = [
  null,
  null,
  [
    { id: "1", value: "abc" },
    { id: "2", value: "def" },
  ],
  [
    { id: "1", value: "efg" },
    { id: "2", value: "jkl" },
  ],
  null,
  [
    { id: "1", value: "an" },
    { id: "2", value: "jef" },
  ],
];
const output = myarray.map((node) =>
  node ? node.map((item) => item.value) : node
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I want result should be  like myarray = [null,null,[abc,def],[efg,jkl],null,[an,jef]]

Answer (score 0):

With typescript, you can do it like this:

```
[{name: 'hello'}, null].map(item => item?.name === undefined ? null : item.name)
```

It returns `['hello', null]`.